# What's the difference between unix sort and sort -d

Tags: linux, shell

After some time spent experimenting with unix `sort` I have noticed the following behaviour

`files.list`:

```
betty
./adam
./cyril
```

The result of `sort files.list` is the same as the result of `sort -d files.list`:

```
./adam
betty
./cyril
```

The manual page for `sort` reads:

```
sort [OPTION]... [FILE]...

-d, --dictionary-order
          consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters
```

But it seems that my `sort (GNU coreutils 8.17)` behaves as if `-d` were default. However, I have not found a way to turn it off.

So my question is, is there any difference when invoking sort with or without `-d`? Is it possible to make sort not to ignore nonalphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your LANG environment variable set to?

If it isn't C, try running:

```
LANG=C sort    files.list > c.files.list 
LANG=C sort -d files.list > c-d.files.list
```

and compare the output files with each other and with your original outputs.  You should get the same effect if you set LANG=POSIX, too.